# Form generation from Mongoose Schema object?

Tags: forms, mongoose, pug

I was looking at trying to generate a form based on a Mongoose schema definition. I was having trouble finding where the schema info is tucked away. Where is the path type info etc kept in the object?

Or better, has anyone tried to do this already? I'm using Jade but something that pumps out HTML would also be good.

Answer (score 1):

My little project creates complete CRUD for a mongoose schema.  Its a little rough but
might be useful.
https://github.com/jspears/bobamo

It is very client side though, all the forms are generated (they can be overriden with static versions if it is not what you need).   That is it doesn't use jade, but it does use underscore template on the client and jqtpl on the server to generate the javascript that makes the form.

Wow that was really unclear...   The browser talks to the server via JSON/REST it loads this into an all javascript front end.  This front end is generated on the node server on demand, to the client.  So it easy to modify, and relatively cleanly sepeartes the data from the view.

Answer (score 1):

If you're exporting out your models, ie

```
module.exports = mongoose.model("ModelName", Model)
```

Check in your module's `.schema`. That should have all the info you need.

Comment: This is a poor solution in almost all cases of web dev since you'll need to bundle your front end up, which causes all sorts of problems with Mongoose. The typical answer for help with that tends to be, "Why are you trying to bundle Mongoose! It's for the backend!"

Comment: frontend apart, would you mind to elaborate about why one would not want dynamic forms ?

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend checking out Formage (npm: formage)

https://github.com/Empeeric/formage

You can get good ideas from this project.